# how to use SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() correctly?

Tags: hibernate, session, sessionfactory

```
@Test
public void testGetCurrentSession(){

    Session firstSession=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

    Session secondSession=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

    assertEquals(firstSession,secondSession);
}
```

Why does this unit test fail? It is in the same thread, so why does getCurrentSession() return two different sessions?

I have set the '**current_session_context_class**' to '**thread**' in hibernate.cfg.xml as follows

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread
</property>
```

ps: hibernate version is 4.0.1.

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Which error gives you? Are not equals? Could you show your hibernate configuration to see how is SessionFactory built?